# Attempting Format for ArchLinux, get the “is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!” error

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux

I've been searching and trying for a few hours on this one.

The most common answer/ explanation I saw was that the drive in question was part of a raid array.  However, I have no raid array setup on my machine.

The drive in question is an NVME device which is recognized by the Linux kernel as 'nvme0n1'

I used fdisk to create 3 partitions:
190gb parition with the Linux x86-64 type
900mb swap partition
390mb EUI partition

The drive and none of the partitions are mounted.

mdadm does not recognized the device as an mdadm device.

Anything else I should try?  Thank you.

Comment: You are being economical with the details, don't drip feed. Edit post giving all the commands and all the output from them as well as details of `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0`. There is no partition type of `Linux x86-64` nor `EUI`

Answer (score 0):

I came back to go through the process again and it worked this time (was able to format the linux partitions on the same device without having done anything else that I am aware of).

Sorry for not having provided more details originally, and thank you for attempting to help.